# How to isolate private static functions in Angular / Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

How to isolate `private static functions` of a class into another file.

In my `component.ts` I have lot of static functions and need to put them in another  ts file for better readability purposes. How can I do that ?

Like we can put interfaces in another file and export them is there something similar for static functions too ?

Desired Result is I am able to call `Component.foo()` in **component.ts** file, but `private static foo()` exists in **logic.ts** file . Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're asking.

You can easily create an external class for static files like:

```
export class Logic {
    public static foo() {
        console.log('foo');
    }
}
```

And then in `component.ts` you can call Logic.foo() just fine. However, you can't make foo `private` because then it's not available in Component.  Also, while you rename `Logic` inside component or wherever else, i.e.

```
const LogicalFunctions = Logic;
LogicalFunctions.foo();
```

you can't reference them as a part of Component, a la `Component.foo()`.

Comment: @dota2pro Yup! I do want to point out that there's very little point in renaming `Logic` in your component.ts file. Standard would just be to change the class name to whatever you really wanted and then import and reference it that way in `Component`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

You can have a file logic.ts:

```
export function foo(){ }
```

And then in your Component-class import this into a private static property if you don't mind an extra step in calling your functions.

```
import * as Logic from './Logic'

class Component
{
    private static Logic = Logic; 

    public DoStuff() {
        Component.Logic.foo();
    }
}


Component.Logic.foo(); // Not allowed
```

Of course anyone could reuse Logic.ts, but if your aim with "private" just is to limit the API of `Component`, it might be an idea.

And of course your `foo` won't have access to other private statics of Component, but if you need that I don't see the point in trying to separate your class into multiple files.

Comment: @dota2pro Maybe you give your class too many responsibilities if you are having problem with it being to big?